# Validating a node body

Tags: 8, hooks

hello i am trying to validate the content of the node body for certain text having some trouble with it. it outputs an message "array".

```
function test_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  // Custom validate function.
  $form['#validate'][] = 'submitForm';
}

function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $author = $form_state->getValue('author');
  $body = $form_state->getValue('body');
  $title = $form_state->getValue('title');
  drupal_set_message('Thanks for submitting the form! you typed in the following as author:' . $author . ' . body:' . $body . '. title:' . $title);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You get the outputs message as an array, because you supplied `$body` and `$title` as arrays, and `$form_state->getValue('author');` doesn't give you author of node test with the following code:

```
function test_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  // Custom validate function.
  $form['#validate'][] = 'validateForm';
}

function validateForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  //- Get the author id.
  $author_uid = $form_state->getValue('uid')[0]['target_id'];
  // Load the author account.
  $author = User::load($author_uid);
  //- Get the body value, if you want just the summary change value by summary. 
  $body = $form_state->getValue('body')[0]['value'];
  //- Get the title value .
  $title = $form_state->getValue('title')[0]['value'];
  //- Use addMessage instead of drupal_set_message its deprecated.
  \Drupal::messenger()->addMessage('Thanks for submitting the form! you typed in the following as author:' . $author->getAccountName() . ' . body:' . $body . '. title:' . $title);
}
```

Don't forget to add the following use:

```
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\user\Entity\User;
```